# Node's "events" module loop/listener. How to exit/terminate it?

Tags: node.js, events

There is something basic I am missing here. I have used async and Q libraries to handle callback hell. I have now realized that using Node's events module is yet another elementary alternative. So, here is my first test example:

```
 ..other requires here...                                                                         
 var eventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
 var myEmitter = new eventEmitter();

 dbConnection = mysql.createConnection(config.dbConnectionParams);
 function myFunc(dbConnection) { 
   insert_values = { name:"John Doe"...insert values...  };  
   MyLib.sqlSpt(dbConnection,"insert into sessionMaster set ? ", insert_values,
          function (err,results,dbConnection) {
             if (results.affectedRows ==1) 
                myEmitter.emit('doneInsert','success'); 
             else 
               myEmitter.emit('doneInsert','fail');
          }); 
 }   
 myFunc(dbConnection);
 myEmitter.once('doneInsert', function(data) {
      console.log('DONE!!! ' + data); 
      myEmitter.removeAllListeners();
 });
```

~

MyLib is just my library. Here it calls a function which is just a wrapper over the mysql dbconnection.query function. The program works fine.
My question is how do I exit the program? Of course, I am not looking at process.exit() option. I presume that the program is continuously waiting for the doneInsert event to be fired. I thought that having removed all eventListeners, and having used "once" rather than "on," the program should exit.

Comment: If the mysql connection is still open the node process won't end - even if there are no more user defined events being listened to.  that mysql connection most likely has its own set of event listeners.

Comment: @Jonah Williams, that was it! dbConnection.end()  in the listener took care of it!! If you post your comment as an answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the mysql connection is still open the node process won't end - even if there are no more user defined events being listened to. that mysql connection most likely has its own set of event listeners.